# Cut for variable delimiter - Bash

Tags: bash, unix, cut

I want to get the second column of a file where separator between column 1 and column 2 is of variable length. 
For example:

```
A1_KOG1494_________AAMFAARSFSERK
A2_KOG1494_______AAKFALRSFSERK
A3_KOG1494___________AAKFALRSFSCCK
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: So you want `KOG1494` or `AAMFAARSFSERK`?

Comment: Just column 2 with "AAMFAARSFSERK" without other things

Comment: Then `tr -s '_' < file | cut -d'_' -f3` should make it.

Comment: @fedorqui That `tr` trick is not foolproof here. What if input string is: `A1KOG1494_______ABCD`?

Comment: @anubhava oh that's is different from what I understood. So column1 is everything up to "at least two __"? In that case, please reopen the question because I got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks I just reopened.

Comment: Wrong dupe closure. Here OP wants to find 2nd field when delimiter is 2 or more underscores. Neither the dupe target question or none of the answers address this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use awk with custom field separator:

```
s='A1_KOG1494_________AAMFAARSFSERK'
awk -F '_{2,}' '{print $2}' <<< "$s"
AAMFAARSFSERK

awk -F '_' '{print $NF}' <<< "$s"
AAMFAARSFSERK
```

Another example:

```
awk -F '_{2,}' '{print $2}' <<< "A3_KOG1494___________AAKFALRSFSCCK"
AAKFALRSFSCCK
```